# Gephi: labelling nodes with LaTeX labels

Tags: latex, nodes, gephi

I am currently working with Gephi and I would like to label the nodes of my network with some mathematical formulae.

Is it possible to add labels written in LaTeX to nodes in Gephi?

I did not find any reference on the internet, just how to export a Gephi network to LaTeX.

I also noticed that labelling of nodes in Gephi has some compatibility problems on my machine with special characters like Greek letters or accented vowels; this is also a motivation to move to LaTeX labels.

References would be great.